# Prepare Dynamic JSON Body

Tags: rest-api, json

I would like to prepare Dynamic JSON Body on the below mentioned format.

```
{
    "MyData": [{
        "id": "SFDC-Contact1",
        "name": "SFDC-Contact",
        "description": "Contact Details",
        "Popularity": "Public",
        "dataTypes": [{
            "name": "Id",
            "gdprFineLevel": "High",
            "description": "ID of Contact",
            "dataRole" :null
        }, {
            "name": "Name",
            "gdprFineLevel": "High",
            "description": "Complete name of Contact"
        }],
        "FCLR": null,
        "DMS": null
    }]
}
```

I have used json string generator for a POST request body from salesforce to a third party. Below is JSON body i am getting.

```
{
  "personalData" : {
    "id" : "SFDC-Contact1",
    "name" : "SFDC-Contact"
  }
} {
  "dataTypes" : [ {
    "name" : "Contact ID",
    "gdprFineLevel" : "High",
    "description" : "ID of Contact"
  }, {
    "name" : "Deleted",
    "gdprFineLevel" : "High",
    "description" : "ID of Contact"
  } ]
}
```

Thanks,
Anil Kumar

Comment: I think wrapping data into wrapper classes  and returning it can solve your problem. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can build nested `Map<String, Object>` and `List<Object>` and serialize those if the content is very dynamic as mentioned in a deleted answer. (If the content is of fixed format [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) often works well.)

For example:

```
Map<String, Object> type = new Map<String, Object>();
type.put('name', 'Id');
...

List<Object> types = new Map<Object>();
types.add('dataTypes', type);

Map<String, Object> item = new Map<String, Object>();
item.put('id', 'SFDC-Contact1');
...

List<Object> myData = new List<Object>();
myData.add(item);

Map<String, Object> root = new Map<String, Object>();
root.put('MyData', myData);

String jsonString = JSON.serializePretty(root);
```